# WP Elementor w/ Contact Form 7 - Display File Upload Location in Textfield

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

So I did some styling on the file upload button (default look didn't match the overall look of the site) and was able to achieve to make the button look styled but I lost the location textfield where it shows the location of the file.

Here is the CSS I added in Elementor's Custom CSS under Essential Addons Contact Form 7 to make the button stylish:

```
/* Style wrapping span as button */
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.file-468 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #699FDE;
    /*border: solid 1px #4096ee;*/

    color: #FFF;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* Made input big and move it left and top inside wrapper to hide actual control but leave input clickable */
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1000px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;        
    outline: none !important;
}

/* Add button text */
.wpcf7-file:before {
    content: "Browse";
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.file-468:hover {
    background: #40B8F4;
}
```

This is how I have the form section in contact form 7:

```
<label style="color: white;"> Full Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label style="color: white;"> Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label style="color: white;"> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label style="color: white;"> Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

<label style="color: white;"> File Upload
[file file-468 id:fileuploadfield class:fileuploadfield]</label>

[text uploadtextfield id:uploadtextfield class:uploadtextfield]

[submit "Send"]
```

And this is the jQuery script I am trying to use inside contact form 7's additional settings but no success so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  /*Click function of fileupload button when text field is clicked*/
    $("#uploadtextfield").click(function() {
        $('#fileuploadfield').click()
    });

  /*Click function of fileupload button when browse button is clicked*/
    $("input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file").click(function() {
        $('#fileuploadfield').click()
    });

  /*To bring the selected file value in text field*/    
    $('#fileuploadfield').change(function() {
    $('#uploadtextfield').val($(this).val());
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PS: instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {})(jQuery);` simply use `jQuery(function($){});`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the correction